# User Dictionary Sync Issue on Marshmallow

Tags: dictionary

Even though I’ve turned on the dictionary sync ON on both my Nexus 4 and 6p [to my Gmail account], still the dictionary does not sync on my 6p. What could be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Google removed programmatic access to the keyboard.

Please vote there to remove this restriction

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3167